# SWTBot: Error while running with tycho

Tags: junit, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, swtbot, tycho-surefire-plugin

We are writing SwtBot test cases for eclipse RCP application, it is working fine in eclipse. Now we are integrating test suite with existing tycho so that while creating product test case can also execute. Pom.xml created for SWTBot test suite is mentioned below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.test.demo.client.gui</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>

    </parent>
  <artifactId>com.tsystem.demo.client.gui.swtbot.test</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>
  <name>demoEVO GUI :: USER SWTBOT</name>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.20.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <useUIHarness>true</useUIHarness>
          <useUIThread>false</useUIThread>
          <!-- use our product and application to launch the tests -->
          <product>com.test.demo.client.gui.ui.product</product>
          <application>com.test.demo.client.gui.ui.application</application>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

We have also include the SWTBot Module in parent pom.xml and it looks like mentioned below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.test.demo.client.gui</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>demoEVO GUI :: PARENT</name>

    <modules>
        <module>com.test.demo.client.gui.ui</module>

        <module>com.test.demo.client.gui.feature</module>
        <module>com.test.demo.client.gui.product</module>
        <module>com.tsystem.demo.client.gui.swtbot.test</module>

    </modules>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipse</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>${eclipse-site}</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>orbit</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>${orbit-site}</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ajdt</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>${ajdt-site}</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>p2-babel</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/update-site/R0.11.1/indigo</url>
        </repository>
           <repository>
     <id>swtbot</id>
     <layout>p2</layout>
     <url>http://download.eclipse.org/technology/swtbot/releases/latest/</url>
   </repository>

    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <tycho-version>0.20.0</tycho-version>
        <platform-version-name>indigo</platform-version-name>
        <eclipse-site>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/${platform-version-name}</eclipse-site>
        <orbit-site>http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20110523182458/repository</orbit-site>
        <ajdt-site>http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/37/update/</ajdt-site>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                    <resolver>p2</resolver>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.test.demo.client.gui.framework.core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                com.test.demo.client.gui.automation.ui
            </artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.test.demo.client.gui.key.ui</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                com.test.demo.client.gui.parameter.ui
            </artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                com.test.demo.client.gui.station.ui
            </artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.test.demo.client.gui.user.ui</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.test.demo.client.gui.monitor.ui</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                com.test.demo.client.gui.transfer.ui
            </artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

we are getting below error while tycho try to execute SWTBot test cases

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:0.20.0:test (default-test) on project com.tsystem.rvs.client.gui.swtbot.test: An unexpected er
ror occured (return code -1). See log for details. -> [Help 1]
```

In the log file it is not able to resolve the application plugins dependency. Here is the contents of log file:

```
!SESSION 2014-08-01 16:21:02.349 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_45
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.uitest -testproperties D:\demo_EVO_PRODUCT_SWT\com.test.demo.client.gui\trunk\com.tsystem.demo.client.gui.swtbot.test\target\surefire.properties -testApplication com.test.demo.client.gui.ui.application -product com.test.demo.client.gui.ui.product -nouithread
Command-line arguments:  -data D:\demo_EVO_PRODUCT_SWT\com.test.demo.client.gui\trunk\com.tsystem.demo.client.gui.swtbot.test\target\work\data -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.uitest -testproperties D:\demo_EVO_PRODUCT_SWT\com.test.demo.client.gui\trunk\com.tsystem.demo.client.gui.swtbot.test\target\surefire.properties -testApplication com.test.demo.client.gui.ui.application -product com.test.demo.client.gui.ui.product -nouithread

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-01 16:21:03.564
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-01 16:21:03.564
!MESSAGE Bundle com.tsystem.demo.client.gui.swtbot.test_6.0.0.qualifier [1] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.tsystem.demo.client.gui.swtbot.test 2 0 2014-08-01 16:21:03.564
!MESSAGE Missing host com.test.demo.client.gui.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.tsystem.demo.client.gui.swtbot.test 2 0 2014-08-01 16:21:03.564
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.test.demo.client.gui.framework.core_6.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-01 16:21:03.564
!MESSAGE Bundle com.test.demo.client.gui.ui_6.0.0.201408011050 [2] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.test.demo.client.gui.ui 2 0 2014-08-01 16:21:03.564
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.test.demo.client.gui.framework.core_6.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-01 16:21:03.564
!MESSAGE Bundle com.test.demo.client.gui.framework.core_6.0.0.201408010530 [6] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.test.demo.client.gui.framework.core 2 0 2014-08-01 16:21:03.564
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

Please let me know what is wrong with the configuration?

Comment: And you have a second problem: `Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7` - apparently you are using a 1.6 JDK to run your build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your product a JUnit test runner? If not, you cannot configure it as the `<product>` in the tycho-surefire-plugin configuration. If you do, there is no test runner and hence no tests will be executed.

If you want to ensure that your product is part of the test runtime, you need the following configuration instead:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <dependency-resolution>
            <extraRequirements>
                <requirement>
                    <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
                    <id>your-product-iu-id</id>
                    <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
                </requirement>
            </extraRequirements>
        </dependency-resolution>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```